# How to do countIf() in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, countif

How do I select a variable which gives an output the same as the excel function:

```
COUNTIFS(A1:D1,"<25", A1:D1, ">16")?
```

I.e. to count the number of times the values in my four fields are between 16 and 25.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with `count()` and `case` expressions. Note: `case` has an optional `else` clause; if it is not used, then the default `else` "value" is `null`. Count only counts non-null values, so you can combine these observations to write compact code. WHAT is counted doesn't matter; so the `case` expression may return a number (1 is usual, but 0 is just as valid and will give the same result, since the values are COUNTED, not SUMMED) - but you could also have a string like 'x' or a date in the case expression. Just to illustrate that, I will use a string.

```
select count( case when col > 16 and col < 25 then 'x' end ) as ct from your_table;
```

Here `your_table` is the name of your table, `col` is the name of the **column** containing the values, and `ct` is the name of the resulting column (the label for the count of values that satisfy your condition).

Of course, in a database you can get the same result more easily:

```
select count(*) as ct from your_table where col > 16 and col < 25;
```

Note, though, that the values are in one column.

If instead you have a table with four COLUMNS and many rows, and all the values in all columns are numbers, and you want to add a column showing how many values are strictly between 16 and 25 IN EACH ROW, the solution is different (but it uses the same ideas):

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, 
       case when col1 > 16 and col1 < 25 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when col2 > 16 and col2 < 25 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when col3 > 16 and col3 < 25 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when col4 > 16 and col4 < 25 then 1 else 0 end    as ct
from   my_table;
```

Answer (score 4):

You would do this in a SQL query using `case`:

```
select sum(case when col between 16 and 25 then 1 else 0 end)
from t;
```

Note that `between` is inclusive in SQL, not exclusive, so based on your code logic:

```
select sum(case when col > 16 and col < 25 then 1 else 0 end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think, you have a `'user_table'`, where some of the user's **'status'** are `active (code-11)` and others are `inactive (code-22)`. You can count active and inactive with this `sql` below.

`select count(case when status = 11 then 1 end) u_active, count(case when status = 22 then 1 end) u_inactive,  from user_table;`